# Connection to report server unsuccessful

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am calling connection to report database inside my **C#** program. Every time when I try to communicate with the server i get

> connection string is not valid

Or

> Report Server Url Invalid parameter

I have checked the connection string and the report server contents as well. It all seems to be correct but still unable to connect to the server.

All the SQL services are running Ok when I try to connect and I have made sure TCP\IP and Name Pipes are enabled in both Client/Server Network Configuration.

Am suspecting it might be a permission issue.

I am using Form authentication on Win 8.1 Pro running SQL server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012. I understand the process of window authentication, and i can see no errors at all. I have been stuck for a while now on this issue and I am feeling a bit lost.

Any help is appreciated

Sites I referred to for help : http://connectionstring.com, http://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.sg/2012/09/forms-authentication-in-ssrs-2012.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to log into SQL Server and view the error log? Log into SQL Server and execute the following:

```
xp_readerrorlog
```

The error log could show shed some light

Could you also post your connection string/Report Server URL?

Comment: Hi @Louie ,thanks for your reply. My connection string inside C# program is                 "Server=SERVERNAME\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=UserAccounts;User Id=SA;Password=Somepassword;")) and report server URL is http://servername/ReportServer

Comment: Executing above mentioned script inside Database Engine, I am getting this strange text Failed to verify Authenticode signature on DLL 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\ftimport.dll'. I didn't configure any SSL certification in my Report Server.

Comment: The ftimport.dll is related to the full text search engine. If you didnt install it as part of SQL Server the error can be ignored. If there are no errors in the error log that relate to login authentication issues, it seems like the C# program isnt even attempting to connect to SQL at this point. What provider are you using to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: I am using OLEDB. I've tried using with Trusted connection as advised in the tutorial i follow. It is like they are it taking as Window Authentication? So, does that mean the authentication is equal with window authentication? Sorry I have limited knowledge about these things. There are no apparent errors regarding with Report Server login issue.

Comment: Thank you Louie. I have posted new question for c# code  as a fresh since SQL side is rather clear, I guess. If you are keen, please take a look to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442620/how-to-solve-anonymous-logon-is-not-configured