# How to solve Anonymous Logon is not configured

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

Can you guys check my codes? I am getting following error when I try to run my program. What is giving that error, where I did wrong and how can I fix it? I am also having problem connecting to server database( report server invalid url). I am guessing my C# code is giving that issue since I could find no much error in SQL side.
I am following these articles:http://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.sg/2012/09/forms-authentication-in-ssrs-2012.html and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaitanya_medikonduri/2010/03/18/forms-authentication-sample-and-windows-2008/
This error happens after I replaced the GetUserInfo method.
[image: Anonymous Login Errorc]

Comment: When I run the program the other time, I have no waring or errors whatsoever , and my UI pages display perfectly and later it gives me connection string error if I try to connect to SQL.